# Чем отличается Virtual Proxy от Value Holder?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, любой-язык

Фалер в разделе Lazy Load перечисляет несколько способов реализации, где 2 из них это:

- Virtual Proxy
- Value Holder

Однако, что-то не могу увидеть между ними какую-то разницу и профит использования одной подхода перед другим...

Comment: Сходу не нагуглил, кто такой Фалер

Comment: @MikhailIonkin https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4884925/

Comment: гм. Обычно шаблоны с "внешне одинаковой реализацией" отличаются ключевым аспектом поведения или использования - и потому считаются разными шаблонами. Но в данном случае и реализация то разная. Первый - мимикрирующий под реальный объект прокси, скрывающия lazy, а второй - явная lazy фабрика, с явным lazy поведением.